# How to get called when a user selected text within Flutter htmlWidget with start and end index values and modify menu buttons after selected text?

Tags: flutter, select, text, area

I'm using flutter latest flutter 3.x and flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.10.0:

...
`Widget getHtml(BuildContext context, String str)
{
String strHtml = "${getHtmlString(str)}  ";
var document = parse(strHtml);
return  SingleChildScrollView(
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
child: SelectionArea(child: HtmlWidget(
document.outerHtml,
),
),

```
     //   onSelectionChanged: htmlSelected,  
      ),  
  );
```

}`
...

What is working: selected text in HtmlWidget, but how to get index values where selected text begins and ends? And how to get event after selected text, so that is possible change menubuttons before to show modified those buttons before to change html data?